# Multiple image links on a form using input type=image

Tags: php, image, forms

I have multiple images on a form along with text input. The images need to contain links and the chosen link needs to be submitted in POST format (so I can capture the data in the text input fields). The source for the images is dynamic (so setting the background for a type=button can't be done in a css file). The following code is not actual code but is an example only (so please forgive any basic errors). My idea is to use `<input type=image>` for each image and a corresponding hidden field to store each image's link. I know this will work. My question is, is there a better or more standard way. I know that `<input type=image>` is for an image map and I am just using / abusing what is available, but I can't think of a better way. Thanks for your input.

```
<form method=post action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?dosomething=true  enctype='multipart/form-data'>

<?php
    $i=0;
    foreach ($files as $file){
?>

        <input type="text" name='user-input<?php echo $i ?>'>
        <input type="image" name='img<?php echo $i ?>' src='<?php echo $file ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name='img<?php echo $i ?>url' value='<?php echo $file ?>'>

<?php
    }
?>
```

When the form loads, check the post values:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val){
    if (substr($key,0,3)=="img"){
        $akey = explode("_",$key);
        $url = $_POST[$akey[0] . "url"];
        // do some processing with user input before leaving form...
        header("Location: " . $url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: not a solution but you are missing quotes `type="image"` is the valid syntax

Comment: Thanks, I spotted it as well and corrected the three types.

Comment: if you can use jQuery, you can do this more easily

Comment: No doubt, but it needs to be completely php based.

Comment: Could you not define inline CSS (or even a generated stylesheet) rather than using `<input type="image">`?

Comment: I can get a button type="submit" to display an image. Is that any better? I of course still have to store the link in a hidden field.

Comment: Did you try use $_FILES instead of $_POST to get the upload file information ???

Comment: In this example I am managing files local to the server, so that is not an issue. Thanks for the thought. In the end, I went with a `<button type="submit" ... `>`<img src="..." height="40"`>`</button`> solution.